# Ruby three-way transitive comparison

Tags: arrays, ruby

I want to compare three arrays transitively to see if there are any shared elements:

```
arrs = [
["AAA", "", ""],
["", "", "CCC"],
["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
]
```

I want to return a matrix that compares the elements transitively. That is, if two arrays share any of the same elements, or if they match with a third record, return `1`. Otherwise return `0`.

With this example the result should be:

```
result = [
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1]
]
```

`result[0][0]` is `1` because if we compare `arrs[0]` with `arrs[0]` (compare itself), they share `"AAA"`.

`result[0][1]` is `1` because if we compare `arrs[0]` and `arrs[1]` there are no shared elements, but both `arrs[0] & arrs[2]` and `arrs[1] & arrs[2]` return an intersecting element, so we return `1`

`result[0][2]` is `1` because if we compare `arrs[0]` with `arrs[2]`, they share `"AAA"`

We repeat the process for all other array combinations in `arrs`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I don't see a question mark anywhere in your query, but I think I follow your intent. I am hesitant to assume. Please articulate your question explicitly. Thank you.

Comment: @tadman and I interpreted your question differently and therefore arrived at different results. You need to clarify (by editing) what you mean by "transitivity". It would be helpful to have an example that does not produce an array of arrays containing nothing other than `1`'s.

Answer (score 2):

It's really not that tricky, you just need to double-[`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-map) here:

```
def transitive(arr)
  arr.map do |a|
    arr.map do |b|
      (a & b).any? ? 1 : 0
    end
  end
end
```

A more Ruby approach is to use `true` or `false`, but `1` and `0` is fine if you can handle the ternary to convert it.

How it works:

```
arrs = [
  ["AAA", "", ""],
  ["", "", "CCC"],
  ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
]

transitive(arrs)
# => [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Not a very exciting example. Here's one that has more variety:

```
arrs = [
  %w[ A B C ],
  %w[ A D E ],
  %w[ D E F ]
]

transitive(arrs)
# => [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Where that has some misses.

Comment: We get different answers, no doubt because we did not share the same understanding of the question.

Answer (score 1):

**Assumption**

We are given an array `arr` of size `n`, each element being an array of size `m`. We wish to construct another `n x m` array, `a`, such each element `a[i][j]` equals `1` (else `0`) if all of the following arrays are non-empty:

```
a[i] & a[i] #  non-empty if a is non-empty
a[i] & a[(i+1)%n]
a[(i+1)%n] & a[(i+2)%n]
a[(j-1)%n] & a[j]
```

This is what I interpret "transitive" to mean. Note that I've assumed the transitive relation "wraps around" from the last to the first element of `arr`.

Let's consider an example.

```
arr = [["A", "B", "C"],
       ["A", "D", "E"],
       ["D", "E", "F"]]
```

Suppose we wish to compute `a[i][j]` of the array `a` being constructed. This equals `1` (else `0`) if the following arrays are all non-empty:

```
a[1] & a[1]             #=> a[1]        => ["A", "D", "E"]
a[1] & a[2%3]           #=> a[1] & a[2] => ["D"] 
a[(i+1)%n] & a[(i+2)%n] #=> a[2] & a[1] => []
```

Note that had `(a[1] & a[2%3]).empty? #=> true`, it would not be necessary to compute the third expression (or any following expressions if `arr` were larger).

For `i #=> 0`,

```
a[0,0] = (arr[0] & arr[0]).any?
  #=> arr[0].any? #=> true, hence = 1
a[0,1] = (arr[0] & arr[1]).any?
  #=> ["A"].any? #=> true, hence = 1
a[0,2] = (arr[0] & arr[1]).any? && (arr[1] & arr[2]).any?
  #=> (a[0,1] == 1) && ["D"].any? => true && true => true, hence = 1
```

For `i #=> 1`,

```
a[1,1] = (arr[1] & arr[1]).any?
  #=> arr[1].any? #=> true, hence = 1
a[1,2] = (arr[1] & arr[2]).any?
  #=> ["D"].any? #=> true, hence = 1
a[1,0] = (arr[1] & arr[2]).any? && (arr[2] & arr[0]).any?
  #=> (a[1,2] == 1) && [].any? => true && false => true, hence = 0
```

For `i #=> 2`,

```
a[2,2] = (arr[2] & arr[2]).any?
  #=> arr[2].any? #=> true, hence = 1
a[2,0] = (arr[2] & arr[0]).any?
  #=> [].any? #=> false, hence = 0
a[2,1] = (arr[2] & arr[0]).any? && (arr[0] & arr[1]).any?
  #=> (a[2,0] == 1) && ["A"].any? => false && true => false, hence = 0
```

**Code**

```
require 'set'

def transitive(arr)
  n = arr.size
  st = n.times.with_object(Set.new) do |i,st|
       (i..i+n-1).each do |j|
         if j==i
           st << [i,j]
         else
           jj = j % n
           jprev = (j-1) % n
           break unless st.include?([i,jprev]) & (arr[jprev] & arr[jj]).any?
           st << [i,jj]
         end
       end
     end
  Array.new(n) do |i|
    Array.new(arr.first.size) { |j| st.include?([i,j]) ? 1 : 0 }
  end
end
```

**Example**

For `arr` defined earlier,

```
transitive(arr)
  #=> [[1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows:

```
n = arr.size
  #=> 3
st = n.times.with_object(Set.new) do |i,st|
       (i..i+n-1).each do |j|
         if j==i
           st << [i,j]
         else
           jj = j % n
           jprev = (j-1) % n
           break unless st.include?([i,jprev]) & (arr[jprev] & arr[jj]).any?
           st << [i,jj]
         end
       end
     end
  #=> #<Set: {[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]}>
```

`st` is a set of the transitive elements of `arr`. This shows that elements of `arr` with indices `[0, 2]` (order matters) are transitive, but those with indices `[2, 0]` are not (because `st` does not contain `[2, 0]`). Notice that once `[2, 0]` it was determined to not be transitive it was not necessary to check `[2, 1]`.

The last step uses the method [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
Array.new(n) {|i| Array.new(arr.first.size) {|j| st.include?([i,j]) ? 1 : 0}}
  #=> [[1, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 1, 1],
  #    [0, 0, 1]]
```